# How to return a promise from a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

The function `getIdentityTokenDecrypted` is giving me a hard time. I'd like to return the promise from `decryptToken` SERVICE B to `getToken` SERVICE A, to retrieve the token.

Here are the steps I need :

1. Get `outlookService.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync` result. (Gives an encrypted token)
2. Decrypt token via `$http` route `/api/exchange/createAndValidateIdentityToken`. This request returns the token I need in SERVICE A.

How can I get this to work ?

```
/*** SERVICE A ***/

var service = {
    /*...*/
    token: getToken()
};

return service;

function getToken() {
    var token;

    serviceB.getIdentityTokenDecrypted()
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            token = response.data.UniqueUserIdentification;
            return token;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return null;
        });
}

/*** SERVICE B ***/

function getIdentityTokenDecrypted() {
    var token = null;
    var promise;

     // This async call does not return a promise,
     // I don't think I can chain after it.
     outlookService.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(function (res) {
         token = res;
     });

     // That's why I use an interval
     promise = $interval(function () {
         if (token != null) {
             $interval.cancel(promise);
             return decryptToken();
         }
     }, 100);

     function decryptToken() {
         var location = window.location.href;

         // I need to get the 'data' from the success
         // of this request to retrieve the token
         return $http({
             method: "POST",
             url: "/api/exchange/createAndValidateIdentityToken",
             data: JSON.stringify({
                 userIdentityToken: token,
                 location: location
             })
         });
     };
     return promise;
};
```

Comment: There is  the first parameter that is a callback method : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142236.aspx Though it leads to the same issue, I don't know how to return the promise of the $hhtp call from this callback function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `outlookService.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync` provides a callback, you don't need `$interval`. You can promise-ify any async function that gives you a callback, by creating your own promise (this is fine when it's unavoidable) and then settling it with the promise you get from `$http` when you have it (which you won't until your callback for `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` is triggered).

I don't "do" Angular, but apparently [`$q` has a "streamlined" syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) rather like ES2015's:

```
promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    outlookService.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync(function (res) {
        if (/*...presumably there's some failure condition...*/) {
            reject(/*...*/);
        } else {
            token = res;
            resolve(decryptToken());
        }
    });
});
```

(I'd probably also modify `decryptToken` to accept the token as an argument rather than having the `token` variable.)

The key bit there is that if you resolve a promise with another promise, that will propagate through the chain.

Comment: "Use callback, not $interval", you're right that made no sense.^^

Comment: @Elfayer: I'm embarrassed to say I didn't notice you were using the callback until I'd already written most of the answer, which opened with that same paragraph followed by "But that doesn't change the fact that you have to somehow get a promise out of a callback situation" and then showed the above, but with the interval. Fortunately I caught it in time. :-) But now I've just removed the first paragraph entirely, it didn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Since this is AngularJS OP's talking about, it would be better to go with the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead. It's pretty much the same syntax, but wrapped in a `$watch`

Comment: @Guilherme I looked into it, I don't really get the use to create a promise manually since the $http returns one.

Comment: @Guilherme: Thanks. I'd be guessing. If you want to post an answer copying the above with with the correct syntax, I'd be happy to delete this one in favor of yours. Or I think you can suggest an edit even though you can't directly edit.

Comment: @Elfayer: You don't have the `$http` promise until after the callback, which is long after your `getIdentityTokenDecrypted` has returned. So you need to create your own to return. Then you settle *your* promise using `$http`'s promise as the resolution value, which then propagates through the chain. (You're quite right to avoid creating promises where possible, creating unnecessary promises is a very common pitfall.)

Comment: @Elfayer: Looks like `$q` supports very ES2015-like syntax, I've updated (and linked).

Comment: I'm not sure I would choose to resolve a promise with another promise if I could avoid it. `resolve(decryptToken());` could be replaced with `decryptToken().then(resolve)`, which would avoid the need for unwrapping and is, in any case, more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @Elfayer: Your code calling "Service A" expects `getToken` to *return* something, but `getToken` doesn't return anything. Perhaps you meant for the `serviceB.getIdentityTokenDecrypted()` line in `getToken` to be `return serviceB.getIdentityTokenDecrypted()`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: There is no *"is"* in aesthetics, there is only *"seems to me"*. Sure, you can do it that way if you like.